# How can I limit the area in which players spawn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

In the latest vanilla Minecraft server, `spawn-protection` and the radius in which players first spawn are identical. If, for example, I want to protect a 100-block-wide village around spawn, players without personally set spawn points will spawn anywhere in that 100x100 area. This is different from all of the documentation I see, which states spawning only occurs in a 20x20 area. Is there any way in the latest version to limit the area in which players spawn so that it is less than my `spawn-protection` area?

Comment: Bukkit or vanilla server?

Comment: @aman207 Vanilla 1.7.4

Answer (score 2):

As of 1.7.2, the world spawn can be set via the `/setworldspawn` command. Usage:

```
/setworldspawn (X) (Y) (Z)
```

**Source:** https://minecraft.wiki/w/13w43a

Comment: Does this set the exact point, or just the center of the area?

Comment: @diras2 This selects the exact block you specify.

Answer (score 2):

First set the center of the spawning area:

```
/setworldspawn
```

Then, set the spawning radius to `0` to make sure that players spawn on *exactly* that block:

```
/gamerule spawnRadius 0
```

Answer (score 2):

To move the world spawn, go to your selected area of spawn and use command `setworldspawn`. Now players will spawn on or near the selected spawn area (usually within 20 blocks away). If you would like it so only the specific block is spawned on (instead of the specific area) then use `gamerule spawnradius <any number>`. Keep in mind the gamrule command only works on certain versions of the game.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the spawn point with [MCEdit](http://www.mcedit.net/). Here is a video in which it tells you how to do that.

Per requested I  have summarized the video.

1. Open mcedit.
2. Click the move spawn point button.
3. Place the spawn point.
4. Save and exit.

Comment: How will this solve my problem? And can you summarize the video for those who can't watch it all right away?

Comment: This makes it so that the user spawns in a specified spot... ill edit it.

Answer (score -1):

You may be looking for [this:](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/48340/96763)

> On a purely vanilla server, you can't. There are no built-in tools or
>   commands to move the spawn point. However, without necessarily using
>   mods like Bukkit, you can still use external tools to modify the
>   level.dat file to change the spawn point.
>
> You can use a program like NBTEdit or NBTExplorer (or NEINedit if on a
>   Mac) to open your level.dat file inside your world folder. Then change
>   the values for SpawnX, SpawnY, and SpawnZ to the coordinates you'd
>   like for your new spawn.
>
> Note that moving the spawn will also move the protected block radius,
>   so keep that in mind.