# World Spawn Location

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I used /setworldspawn to set the spawn point on the server, and I have a command block on a clock that tp's all new players to a custom first spawn point (based on players within a radius of 30 around spedific co-ordinates). I have all the command block stuff that makes the server go under there, and use that spot to execute commands on players that only need to be run once.

I increased the spawn protection in the server.properties because I kept having issues with hackers wrecking things at spawn (despite enforcing gamemode 2, etc within the spawn area), and now when players first join, they seem to spawn in any random place within the spawn protected area (which is not what I want). Is there any work around for this, or is this just how an increased spawn protection in server.properties is going to function?

Comment: Personally, to combat cheaters I would always go with a server plug-in rather than command blocks.

Comment: I'm running the server as vanilla, so plugins wouldn't work for me. (Long story, but it's got to stay vanilla). Was hoping there could be an easy fix...

Comment: Please check if [**this**](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/296877/170284) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the spawn area to as small as you can, and then remove all land around it.

This way, cheaters have nothing to break when they spawn -- it's just air.

If you can get the command blocks to work remotely (which I think you are, if I read your post right), then they won't be able to break the command blocks either.

Alternatively, you could do this with Bedrock.

As a side note, especially if this doesn't work for you, you may want to change the title of this post to a question. The current one doesn't tell anyone what your actual *question* is.